# Lightweight Alternative to Outlook Mail Client?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, email-client

Frankly, I can't run Outlook. I have to keep my computer lean since I run my developer tools in a VM and the 20+ threads it spins up by default is just killer.  This means I only read my work emails on my phone and when I have to do a longer reply or copy a link I have to go to the crappy Microsoft Online Services exchange site.

This is a hassle.

I don't need calendar, I don't need tasks, I just need simple read and send access to my outlook email that works better than the exchange website. I don't even need notifications since I got it on my phone.

Does anyone have a simple, free, lightweight alternative to using the outlook mail client/exchange website? Heck, I'd settle for a powershell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No personal experience, but [Sylpheed](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/en/) looks good...

[Claws Mail](http://www.claws-mail.org/).  Another lightweight email client.

Answer (score 1):

I use TrulyMail which works great.